# Selecting an option and posting its value, in the result have that option automatically selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a select element which posts some data to a php script using ajax.

My html looks like this:

```
<select id="productoptiekeuze" class="productchoice" required="">
   <option value="">Maak uw keuze</option>
   <option value="0" data-src="45">€ 45&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 60 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: century oak&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: kunststof&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <option value="1" data-src="45">€ 45&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 60 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: century oak&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: kunststof&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <option value="2" data-src="55">€ 55&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 80 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: dark oak&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: kunststof&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <option value="3" data-src="55">€ 55&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 80 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: grey&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: graniet&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <option value="4" data-src="55">€ 55&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 80 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: grey&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: graniet&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <option value="5" data-src="95">€ 95&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Formaat: 120 cm&nbsp;&nbsp; Kleur: century oak&nbsp;&nbsp; Materiaal: eik&nbsp;&nbsp; </option>
   <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
</select>
```

The last optgroup is to dirty fix an issue in IOS.

This is my ajax:

```
tpj('#productinfo').on('change', '#productoptiekeuze', function() {
  var $aangepasteprijs = tpj('#productoptiekeuze').find('option:selected').attr('data-src'),
  $huidigeprijs = tpj('#price').text(),
  $oudeprijs = tpj('#oldprice').text(),
  $alias = tpj('input[name="alias"]').val(),
  $quantity = tpj('input[name="quantity"]').val(),
  $value = tpj('#productoptiekeuze').find('option:selected').val(),
  url = 'includes/prodoptie.php';

  var posting = tpj.post( url, {
    aangepasteprijs: $aangepasteprijs,
    huidigeprijs: $huidigeprijs,
    oudeprijs: $oudeprijs,
    alias: $alias,
    quantity: $quantity,
    value: $value
  } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    tpj( "#productinfo" ).empty().append( data );
    tpj('option:contains(' + $value + ')').attr('selected', true);
  });
});
```

I post the value of the selected option to my script, and want to automatically have that option selected in the result. But I get real weird behaviour, sometimes it works, but most of the times I get no response or something entirely different from what I clicked.

Why could that be?

[You can see it functioning here](http://studionewmedia.nl/_extern/badenincl/trendline-60cm/badmeubel-trend-dynasty-met-ronde-kom-60-century-oak) (It's the dropdown above the PLAATS IN WINKELWAGEN button)

My PHP script that is returned has the exact same list and values.

Comment: that's because you are replacing #productinfo content and you don't have the php code where the select option gets selected.

Comment: Are you getting the same data from PHP but it's not displaying correctly or are you also getting different responses from the PHP?

Comment: why are you replacing the content of the select list? Does the ajax call return you some different options or something?

Comment: @Luca If I check in my network I see all posted values are correct. The value I clicked is the one that is posted.

Comment: But is the data returned correct? You didn't share your PHP code, so it could very well be the source of the problem

Comment: @Luca The code that generates the dropdown is exactly the same in my php script as in the initial file. I copy pasted it, and the returned dropdown has the same html markup.

Comment: Why even get new data then?

Comment: Because I get more from that script and my dropdown triggers that. So I created a div around everything and put my jquery on that `(#productinfo)` , or else the dom would already be loaded and my jquery won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that your posting done does not find your option. You should make two divs and only update the content that is needed to update, so your select is not effect by re-adding it.

Otherwise you could try yor posting.done like this:

```
posting.done(function( data ) {
    tpj( "#productinfo" ).empty().append( data );
    tpj('option[value="'+$value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```